# メールサーバー経由でメール送信できない

Tags: postfix

サーバー初級です。
メールサーバー経由でメール送信出来ず苦しんでいます。
考えられそうな原因や確認すべき事を教えていただけないでしょうか？

状況は以下の通りです。
・WEBサーバー（CentOS7）とメールサーバーは別
・ポート465 ※先方より指定
　→この場合メールはメールサーバーを経由との事
　→ユーザ認証(SMTP-AUTH)が必須との事
・WEBサーバーへはpostfixをインストールして設定
・メールサーバーへはアクセス権が無いため、設定の確認、変更等出来ず

このWEBサーバーのドメインのメール（実際に使っているメールアドレス）へのログは`dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)`ですが、他のドメインのメールへ送信しようとした場合は`status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended:`です。

以下、WEBサーバー側での設定です。

[php.ini]

```
SMTP = mail.ドメイン
smtp_port = 465
```

[main.cf]

```
myhostname = mail.ドメイン
mydomain = ドメイン
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP unknown
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
relayhost = smtp.mail.ドメイン:465
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options =
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
relay_domains = $mydestination
```

[sasl_passwd]
smtp.mail.ドメイン reply@ドメイン:パスワード
→hash化
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

情報が不足しておりましたらご指摘いただけますでしょうか？

postfixの設定は今回初めてでしたが、どうしても作業せざるを得ない状況で調べながら何とかここまできました。
どうか、宜しくお願いいたします。

ログを追記します。
Feb  3 22:10:14 www postfix/pickup[10336]: 8F2FEB000143: uid=0 from=
Feb  3 22:10:14 www postfix/cleanup[10341]: 8F2FEB000143: message-id=<20180203131014.8F2FEB000143@mail.ドメイン>
Feb  3 22:10:14 www postfix/qmgr[10337]: 8F2FEB000143: from=, size=469, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  3 22:10:14 www postfix/local[10346]: 8F2FEB000143: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.03/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)
Feb  3 22:10:14 www postfix/qmgr[10337]: 8F2FEB000143: removed

/dev/nullというのはゴミ箱行きらしいですね。

Comment: 「メールサーバーへはアクセス権が無いため、設定の確認、変更等出来ず」とのことですが、メールサーバの担当にログの確認を依頼することもできないのでしょうか?

Comment: ログは省略せずに全文を記載してください。

Comment: ログの確認は、技術面での担当が誰かはっきりせず、困っています。ログの記録失礼しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postfix を使わずに、PHP から SMTPS + SMTP-Auth でメールサーバーに接続できませんでしょうか？

postfix を使う場合、PHP からは localhost(127.0.0.1) の 25番ポートへ接続することになります。
ただし、postfix から外部 MTA へは、587番ポート(StartTLS + SMTP-Auth)では接続できますが、
465番ポート(SMTPS + SMTP-Auth)では接続できなかったと思います。

Comment: 465で接続出来ないというのは知りませんでした。勉強不足でした。PHP から SMTPS + SMTP-Auth というのは経験がありません。調べてみます。

Comment: PEAR::Mailをインストールしてみましたが、今度はパスが通っていないのか、確認してもエラーとなります。
# pear list
pear: コマンドが見つかりません

メール送信が出来ない事は解決していませんが、postfixで465が使えないという事（原因）がわかりましたので、とりあえず次に進めます。ありがとうございました。